# Joining tables on columns with different names but produce single column in result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, join

I'm not sure how to concisely formulate question to describe a problem I would like to solve.
I have two following tables:
`Table 1`

```
[idA] [numA]
 NULL   8
 1      10
 2      15
 3      16
```

`Table 2`

```
[idB] [numB]
 2      14
 3      30
 4      32
```

Now, I'm not sure how to formulate T-Sql query to produce following result:

```
[id] [numA] [numB]
NULL  8      0
1     10     0
2     15     14
3     16     30
4     0      32
```

Are there any suggestions on how to solve this?

**UPDATE:**

---

Would there be any problems with @AdaTheDev's script if there was one more table (idC, numC) to join? In that case what would be the best solution? The thing is I have 15 of them to join into one table and they should be grouped by id and have 15 corresponding numX columns.

Comment: If you have so many tables, or you don't know how many tables there are, you probably have a problem with your database design that can't be solved using SQL query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, should do it

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.idA, t2.idB) AS id, 
    ISNULL(t1.numA, 0) AS numA, 
    ISNULL(t2.NumB, 0) AS numB
FROM table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.idA = t2.idB OR t1.ida IS NULL AND t2.idb IS NULL
```

**Update**
Note I've added an OR condition to the join to handle the case where idA and idB are NULL, to give a single result

Full test script (with added NULL id record in table2):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ida integer, numA INTEGER)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (idb integer, numb INTEGER)

INSERT @Table1 ([ida], [numA])
VALUES (NULL, 8), (1, 10), (2, 15), (3, 16)

INSERT @Table2 ([idb], [numb])
VALUES (NULL, 9), (2, 14), (3, 30), (4, 32)

SELECT ISNULL(t1.idA, t2.idB) AS id, 
    ISNULL(t1.numA, 0) AS numA, 
    ISNULL(t2.NumB, 0) AS numB
FROM @table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN @table2 t2 ON t1.idA = t2.idB OR t1.ida IS NULL AND t2.idb IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 : Though I personally always use explicit braces around boolena logic.  Not only to stop me screwing up, but to stop misunderstanding when it's being read.  `(A = B) OR (A IS NULL AND B IS NULL)` or the like...

Comment: Would there be any problems with this script if there was one more table (idC, numC) to join? The thing is I have 15 of them to join into one table and they should be grouped by id and have 15 corresponding numX columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @table1 AS TABLE (idA INT, numA INT)
DECLARE @table2 AS TABLE (idB INT, numB INT)

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES 
(NULL, 8),
(1, 10),
(2, 15),
(3, 16)

INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES
(2, 14),
(3, 30),
(4, 32)


SELECT COALESCE(ida, idb) AS id, ISNULL(numa, 0) AS numa, ISNULL(numb, 0) AS numb
FROM @table1
FULL OUTER JOIN @table2 ON ida = idb
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
select tableA.idA as Id, tableA.numA as numA, tableB.numB as numB
from tableA
inner join tableB on tableA.Id = tableB.Id
```

Comment: Almost, except it looks like `numB` has to default to 0 when there's no matching row from table A.