# Joining multiple tables into one under one Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, join

I have dozen of tables with following format:

**Table 1**

```
[idA] [numA]
 NULL   8
 1      10
 2      15
 3      16
```

**Table 2**

```
[idB] [numB]
 2      14
 3      30
 4      32
```

**Table 3**

```
[idC] [numC]
 NULL   56
 1      24
 4      37
 5      36
```

**...**

Now, I'm not sure how to formulate T-Sql query in order to produce following result:

```
[id] [numA] [numB] [numC] ...
NULL  8      0      56
1     10     0      24
2     15     14     0
3     16     30     0
4     0      32     37
5     0      0      36
```

Are there any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: how is this different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549952/joining-tables-on-columns-with-different-names-but-produce-single-column-in-resu

Comment: And WHY do you have so many tables? Looks like there is a problem with the database's design

Comment: @bluefeet because in the previous question I've asked for solution not having on my mind that the solution would be rather restricted to only two tables and can't be applied for problem with more tables. This is the question for n tables.

Comment: @panagiotisKanavos these tables are actually views in my db. I have to support solution for isolated and cumulative views.

Answer (score 2):

I offer a solution with the full outer join, because that seems like the natural approach:

```
SELECT coalesce(a.id, b.id, c.id, . . .) as id,
       a.NumA, b.NumB, c.NumC, . . .
FROM TableA a full outer join
     TableB b
     on a.id = b.id full outer join
     TableC c
     on coalesce(a.id, b.id) = c.id
```

However, the query needs to be written carefully, to keep the coalesces in line.  The one advantage of this approach is that it should use indexes on the id columns for the query.

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
select id, max(numa),max(numb),max(numc) from
(
select id,numa,0 as numb,0 as numc from tb1
union all
select id,0 as numa,numb as numb,0 as numc from tb2
union all
select id,0 as numa,0 as numb,numc as numc from tb3
)X
group by id
order by id
```

Thanks
Rajath

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Maintable.id, 
       Table1.numA, 
       Table2.numB, 
       Table3.numC 
FROM   (SELECT ida AS id 
        FROM   Table1 
        UNION 
        SELECT idb AS id 
        FROM   Table2 
        UNION 
        SELECT idc AS id 
        FROM   Table3) MainTable 
       LEFT JOIN Table1 
         ON Maintable.id = Table1.Ida 
       LEFT JOIN Table2 
         ON Maintable.id = Table2.idB 
       LEFT JOIN Table3 
         ON Maintable.id = Table3.idC
```